# Permission Denied: Only authenticated user can access this private project

Tags: python, project-lib

I'm trying to use `project_lib` in a python notebook and getting the following error running the cell that is inserted automatically by using the "insert project token" option:

```
ERROR:__PROJECT_LIB__:ProjectAPIProxy__get_project(): 
   unexpected response status: 
   {"code":401,
    "error":"Unauthorized",
    "reason":"Permission Denied: Only authenticated user can access this private project.",
    "message":"Access denied"}
```

I’m using the spark beta ‘environment’.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: The Spark beta environments are a beta feature. Some things don't work yet. The pre-installed `project_lib` is one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that hummingbird environments (default spark environments) in specific have an old and outdated version of the lib preinstalled. I will open a ticket to upgrade the version of the lib on Hummingbird.